# how to retrieve values from plotly sunburst chart?

Tags: python, plotly, information-retrieval

[Plotly sunburst charts](https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/) are great for visualizing hierarchical data. Is it possible to retrieve the values shown in the chart into a dictionary, or an array or something?

Concretely, assume the following dataframe:

```
Att1   Att2
A      C
A      D
B      D
B      D
B      C
```

`px.sunburst(data, ['Att1', 'Att2'])`  will generate a chart that in the most inner ring has the value 2 for `A` and 3 for `B`. Then for `A`, it will indicate there is 1 `C` and 1 `D`. Similarly, for `B` it will indicate 2 `D` and 1 `C`. All those numbers are the ones I am looking to retrieve. Does plotly have such functionality? or is my best bet to use `data.groupby` iteratively?

Comment: a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help, but i'll take a stab at a general response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying data from a figure can be accessed and the details can be found [here at plotly](https://plotly.com/python/figure-structure/) and summarized below...

> Viewing the underlying data structure for any
> plotly.graph_objects.Figure object, including those returned by Plotly
> Express, can be done via print(fig) or, in JupyterLab, with the
> special fig.show("json") renderer. Figures also support fig.to_dict()
> and fig.to_json() methods. print()ing the figure will result in the
> often-verbose layout.template key being represented as ellipses '...'
> for brevity.

Several options are available...

- `fig.show("json")` is pretty hany if you're in a notebook
- `print(fig)` is my go to method

So for this plotly example:

```
import plotly.express as px
data = dict(
    character=["Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"],
    parent=["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve" ],
    value=[10, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4])

fig = px.sunburst(
    data,
    names='character',
    parents='parent',
    # values='value',
)
fig.show()
```

`print(fig)` will return:

```
Figure({
    'data': [{'domain': {'x': [0.0, 1.0], 'y': [0.0, 1.0]},
              'hovertemplate': 'character=%{label}<br>parent=%{parent}<extra></extra>',
              'labels': array(['Eve', 'Cain', 'Seth', 'Enos', 'Noam', 'Abel', 'Awan', 'Enoch', 'Azura'],
                              dtype=object),
              'name': '',
              'parents': array(['', 'Eve', 'Eve', 'Seth', 'Seth', 'Eve', 'Eve', 'Awan', 'Eve'],
                               dtype=object),
              'type': 'sunburst'}],
    'layout': {'legend': {'tracegroupgap': 0}, 'margin': {'t': 60}, 'template': '...'}
})
```

And then with some knowledge of tuples you can extract some info, for example...

`print(fig.data[0].labels)` will return:

```
['Eve' 'Cain' 'Seth' 'Enos' 'Noam' 'Abel' 'Awan' 'Enoch' 'Azura']
```